# Subnet mask, which allows a maximum number of hosts per subnet

Tags: ip, subnet

Consider a network with id 158.159.0.0. There are two subnets included, with subnet numbers 0.0.160.0 and 0.0.161.128.
Determine the subnet mask, which allows a maximum number of hosts per subnet

---

I know a maximum number of hosts is reached with maximum 0s of Subnet Mask. So should it be 255.255.160.0 ? Or should I write different answers for both subnets ?

The answers found on the Internet relate to determining a number of hosts for a given Subnet Mask. Here is subnet mask not given and number of hosts also not.

Comment: the answer in the link says:
"Calculating the maximum possible number of hosts in a subnet: 
Maximum Number of hosts = 2**(32 - netmask_length) - 2"

So it does not help at all because I know neither number of host nor netmask, so can't solve the equation

Comment: Subnet math is subnet math. It's all the same bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

160 = `1010 0000` Thus 3 important bits: `1110 0000` or `224` (255.255.224.0) **BUT** we know there's a 161 subnet which a /19 would step on. So, the largest 160 can be without treading into 161 is "all bits" -- 255.255.255.0 (/24).

Similarly, 161.128 = `1010 0001.1000 0000` Thus 1 bit in the last octect: 255.255.255.128 (/25)